# predict() gives wrong matrix for bs(); how to predict linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, spline

I've met a problem about function `bs()`.

```
      library(ISLR)    
      library(ggplot2)    
      library(caret)    
      data(Wage)    
      #summary(Wage)        

      set.seed(123)    
      inTrain <- createDataPartition(Wage$wage, p = 0.7, list = F)    
      training <- Wage[inTrain,]    
      testing <- Wage[-inTrain,]    

      library(splines)     
      bsBasis <- bs(training$age, df=3)      
      bsBasis[1:12,] 

      lm1 <- lm(wage ~ bsBasis, data=training)    
      lm1$coefficients    
      ## (Intercept)    bsBasis1    bsBasis2    bsBasis3     
      ##       60.22       93.39       51.05       47.28    

      plot(training$age, training$wage, pch=19, cex=0.5)    
      points(training$age, predict(lm1, newdata=training), col="red", pch=19, cex=0.5)    

      predict(bsBasis, age=testing$age)
```

The dimensions of `predict(bsBasis, age=testing$age)` is *2012x3*, while the `testing$age` got only 988 rows. And the results of `predict(bsBasis, age=testing$age)` is identical to the `bsBasis`.

My questions are:

1. What is `predict(bsBasis, age=testing$age)` actually doing?
2. How to use this `bsBasis` in predicting the `wage` in the TEST data correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your question 1**

Use `newx`. Check `?predict.bs` for its arguments.

```
x <- runif(100)
b <- bs(x, df = 3)
predict(b, newx = c(0.2, 0.5))
```

Different `predict` functions may behave differently. Here, no matter what variable you use in `bs()`, `age`, `sex`, `height`, etc, it can only be `newx` in `predict.bs()`.

**Your question 2**

You don't really need to form explicitly `bsBasis`. When using splines in regression, `lm` and `predict.lm` will hide construction and prediction of spline from you.

```
lm1 <- lm(wage ~ bs(age, df = 3), data=training)
predict(lm1, newdata = test)
```

Note the argument in `predict.lm` is `newdata`.

Comment: Alright, I think you just meant:

The predict() here should be written as:
    
    predict(bsBasis, testing$age)

or

    predict(object=bsBasis, newx=testing$age).

I tried these two ways above, and got a result which I want.